# Robotium fails in the second test

Tags: android, robotium

I've created simple test in my android program using robotium 3.5.1 with the following code:

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}

public void testAddTabs() throws Exception {


    addTab("TAB1");
    addPreset("TAB1");
    addTab("TAB2");
    addPreset("TAB2");


}

public void addTab(String tabName) throws Exception {

    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Checking current Activity",
            MainActivity.class);
    Log.d("MyTag", solo.getCurrentActivity().getLocalClassName() );
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(com.sm.scam.R.id.menu_new_tab));
    solo.enterText(0, tabName);
    solo.clickOnText("OK");

}

public void addPreset(String name) throws Exception {
    Log.d("MyTag", solo.getCurrentActivity().getLocalClassName() );
    solo.goBackToActivity("MainActivity");
    Log.d("MyTag", solo.getCurrentActivity().getLocalClassName() );
    solo.clickOnText(name);
    solo.clickOnText("New Preset");
    Log.d("MyTag", solo.getCurrentActivity().getLocalClassName() );
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Checking current Activity",
            PresetActivity.class);

    String presetName = "Moti" + 1;
    solo.enterText(0, presetName);
    solo.pressSpinnerItem(0, 1);
    solo.clickOnText("Darkened");
    solo.clickOnText("GPS Tag");
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(com.sm.scam.R.id.menu_save_preset));
}
```

it simply add new tab, and in the tab pressing on button, changes edittext,spinner and 2 switch buttons and save.
everything is OK in the first tab but in the second tab the following code:

```
solo.clickOnText("New Preset");
```

just don't do nothing!
when clicking this button nothing happens and it should forward to PresetActivity as it forwarding correctly in the first tab.

the error code:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Checking current Activity expected:<...Preset...>            but was:<...Main...>
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Asserter.assertCurrentActivity(Asserter.java:57)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.assertCurrentActivity(Solo.java:570)
at com.sm.scam.test.ScamTest.addPreset(ScamTest.java:55)
at com.sm.scam.test.ScamTest.testAddTabs(ScamTest.java:32)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at                                                                                                                                                                        android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java   :186)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:537)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1574)
```

I've also tried to force it by calling to:

```
solo.goBackToActivity("MainActivity");
```

but still nothing.
would appreciate if someone help me. thanks

Comment: call solo.sleep(int) after each method...

Comment: already tried that...still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabHost? if so that is probably your problem. TabHosts involve having multiple activities open and this really confuses robotium. That is because robotium only knows about the last activity that it saw, this means in a scenario where multiple activities are open then the one it sees last might not be the one you are expecting it to be.

You can see this is happening because it isn't failing to click on anything it is in fact just on the wrong activity and thats the assertion that fails.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Paul.
As you can see i tried with:
solo.goBackToActivity("MainActivity");
where all the buttons / other views are. and still no luck.
It's not tabHost it's ICS action bar

Comment: My point was that using the goBackToActivity("") method might not be doing what you want and you should just use the solo.goBack() call

Answer (score 0):

This is because sometimes assert executes before your activity was loaded. So try to use before `assertActivity` something like:

```
solo.waitForActivity(getCurrentActivity().getClass().getSimpleName());
solo.assertCurrentActivity(PresetActivity.class);
```

Comment: I add a log statement in the activity's onResume() and then call waitForLogEntry(). Of course that means the code isn't quite the same as released, but this is a 90% solution...

Comment: @ tomwhipple such method works for me fine ... ty for sharing experience